# Как xml файл,скачивает библиотеки из dependencies?

Tags: xml, spring, maven

Имею в виду,что происходит «под капотом».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под капотом у вас листенер (функция, которая анализирует ваш xml файл ~ каждую секунду). Листенер смотрит ссылки ваших репозиториев (файлохранилище, откуда скачиваются библиотеки), а так же анализирует зависимости, которые вы добавляете. Как только появляется новая зависимость, мавен пытается загрузить ее из известных ему репозиториев.

Comment: Стоит так же заметить, что сначала мавен проверяет наличие зависимости в вашем локальном репозитории. Если там ее , тогда скачивает.